# How to track which stories are in certain release in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our organization has moved from Jira to use Azure DevOps. We are not following any set process per se, but our team organizes software development tasks with work items. Epics, Features, Stories... We do stuff and occasionally decide that now is a good time to move all things we've done and tested to production environment. And here comes the issue.

In Jira every time we closed story we could assign it to a 'release'. We had a system where the release would always be called 'next release'. Then when it was time to do the release we just renamed that in Jira to something else, like 'v1.2', and now all the stories would show the release to be 'v1.2'. Then we'd create a new release and give it a name 'next release' and start to assign that to stories. The releases inside Jira were probably just logical containers (like folders) that would organize issues. It was easy to see what has been assigned to 'next release' and what was in 'v1.1-beta' or what ever.

Now I haven't found any simple way to do similar thing in DevOps. They seem to guide you to use the release and deployment pipelines and all the CI/CD thingies... While we probably could do that in some projects, not all projects have something to deploy from DevOps.

Do you have any suggestions how we could achieve something rather similar as we had in Jira? I could probably use Tags? But renaming a tag doesn't work, does it? You'd always have to know which tag to use.

I feel that Azure DevOps really forces you to do things in a certain way and follow a set process.